# Need a CSS like in Tech Crunch blog loop

Tags: css

have a look on this screenshot

[image: screenshot]

I need a CSS of the left side part that have circle in like ... how I make this on for my Blog Post loops like in Tech Crunch.

Comment: You wanna create a circle using css? What is exactly your question?

Comment: I want to create the whole part...

Comment: Can you provide your codes?

Comment: But first I want to create the highlighted part...

Comment: what've you tried yet?

Comment: Sir basically this is from techcruch .com

I have done the php part but I am not good in CSS

Comment: on stackoverflow we DONT DO code for other people, use freelancer for that. We can help you if you have at least tried something

Comment: Please tell me how i submit code here

Comment: Please check : http://pastebin.com/QT0GWcZe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this. I hope it will helps you.

```css
 *{margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: arial;}
 .left-section{width: 160px;border-right: 2px solid #e8e8e8;min-height: 200px;}
 ul{padding: 10px 0;}
 ul li{width: 130px;background: #e8e8e8;font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;height: 30px;padding: 6px;box-sizing:border-box;position: relative;margin-bottom: 10px}
 ul li:before{content: '';width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 16px solid transparent;border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;border-left: 15px solid #e8e8e8;position: absolute;right:-15px;top:0;}
 ul li:after{content: '';height: 12px;width: 12px;background: #fff;border:2px solid #d2d3d2;position: absolute;border-radius:20px;right: -40px;top:8px;}
```

```html
<div class="left-section">
  <ul>
    <li>6 hours ago</li>
    <li>7 hours ago</li>
    <li>8 hours ago</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot friends... you people solved my issue.

Comment: Hello Maddy, Yes it works... how I accept your answer and finished this post ?